# Replacing values in kendo grid

Tags: replace, kendo-ui, grid

I have a problem that I even have an idea where to start looking..
So I have a grid and a column of type of receipts. The values are numbers. How can I replace them with meaningfull values (if type is '0', then I need to display 'CASH'). What is the smartest way to do that?

Code:

```
<?php
require_once(__DIR__ . '/localization/taxesLocalization.php');
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title><?php echo $taxes ?></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/kendo.common-material.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/kendo.material.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom_style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="HtmlTemplates/notifications.php">
        <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/devices.js"></script>
        <script src="js/functions.js"></script>
        <script src="js/FCM.js"></script>
        <script src="js/functions/confirm_window.js"></script>
        <script src="js/MessageTypes/message_types.js"></script>
        <script src="js/functions/show_notification.js"></script>
        <script src="js/taxes_scripts/constants.js"></script>
        <script src="js/taxes_scripts/functions.js"></script>
        <script src="js/functions/duplicates_check.js"></script>
        <script src="js/taxes_scripts/services.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav>
            <div id="toolbar"></div>
            <?php include "navmenu.php"; ?>
        </nav>
        <span id="popupNotification"></span>
        <br>
        <div class="" style="width: 100%;">
            <div>
                <div id="device_container">
                    <label for="devices" ><b><?php echo $devices ?></b></label>
                    <input id="device-report" style="width: 270px" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div id="gridSession"></div>
              <div id="grid"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>

<script>
    var device_ID = 510;


    const X_SESSION = "./services/ReportsServices/getXSessionInfo.php?device_ID=";
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: X_SESSION + device_ID,
                    dataType: "json"
                }
            },
            schema: {
                data: "data",
                model: {
                    id: "id",
                    fields: {
                        sequence: {},
                        datestart: {},
                        total: {},
                        type: {},
                        receipt_count: {},
                        from_ticket: {},
                        to_ticket: {},
                        date_start: {},
                        date_end: {}
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: dataSource,
            navigatable: true,
            scrollable: true,
            resizable: true,
            sortable: true,
            filterable: false,
            height: $(document).height() - 120,
            columns: [
                {field: "sequence", title: "Slijed"},
                {field: "datestart", title: "Početak sesije"},
                {field: "total", title: "Ukupno na računu"},
                {field: "type", title: "Način plačanja "},
                {field: "receipt_count", title: "Broj računa"},
                {field: "from_ticket", title: "Od kartice"},
                {field: "to_ticket", title: "Do kartice"},
                {field: "date_start", title: "Datum prvog računa"},
                {field: "date_end", title: "Datum zadnjeg računa"}

            ]
        }).data("kendoGrid");

        $("#device-report").kendoComboBox(
           );

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `template` on the grid column which will check the value of `type` and update the column field accordingly:

```
{field: "type", title: "Način plačanja", template: "#if (type == 0) {# CASH #} else {# Another value #}#"}
```

**EDIT**

Haven't used `switch` in a `template` column before but something like this should be pretty close:

```
{field: "type", title: "Način plačanja", template: "#var value; switch(type){ case 0: value = 'CASH'; break; case 1: value = 'Another value'; break; case 3: value = 'ANOTHER value'; break; default: value = 'Default value'; }##=value#"}
```

Comment: hey its possible to do that with a switch case somehow?

Comment: Check the update... Untested but pretty confident it should be darn close :)

Comment: i managed to fit them with if-s, but now i have a second problem, i need to localize the strings, and i do it with php, how can i replace {# CASH #} with {# <?php echo cash?> #}, because it say unterminated string literal..

Comment: If I was you, I'd ask a new question for that as I am unsure about `php` usage with Kendo controls.